# Where can I obtain the specification for Distributed Relational Database Architecture?

Tags: db2, ibm, dbms

I'm developing a DBMS that should be able to connect to IBM DB2 via the [DRDA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DRDA) protocol. I found a DRDA reference manual that mentions "DRDA Implementation Programmer's Guide, SC21-9529" as a publication about DRDA, and seems that this manual is exactly what I was looking for. The problem is, I am unable to find it on the net.

Where can I obtain this document or another comparable document that explains implementing DRDA?

Comment: You should try calling IBM.  They might make the document available to you for a nominal fee.  There is also this: http://www.opengroup.org/dbiop/

Comment: To those flagging: I have yet to see a reason to close this. I searched under both the document title and document ID and there is no apparent way to purchase or download this document. There is no reference to it being superceded by another document. There is nothing, aside from it's name being referenced in other documents. Someone familiar with this specification should be able to point toward where to obtain this publication or other, similar, useful documents that cover the same topics.

Comment: @ThomasOwens: The only real problem that I have with this question is that it can only be answered with a link, and link-only answers are specifically discouraged on the SE network.

Comment: @RobertHarvey I would expect some additional text that identifies the publisher of the document, date of publication, if there is ongoing work to revise the document, and so on.

Comment: @ThomasOwens: Alright, I will try that.

Comment: @RobertHarvey: I understand that link requests aren't favored in SE community, but this publication is hard to find, so I'm asking for help here. Also I think it might be usefull for the community.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Distributed Relational Database Architecture (DRDA) Version 5 standard  is available online as a free PDF download from [The Open Group's Publications Catalog.](http://www.opengroup.org/dbiop/)  It comprises 3 volumes:

- C112 DRDA V5 Vol. 1: Distributed Relational Database Architecture
  (806 pages)
  https://www2.opengroup.org/ogsys/jsp/publications/PublicationDetails.jsp?publicationid=12360
- C113 DRDA V5 Vol. 2: Formatted Data Object Content Architecture (110
  pages)
  https://www2.opengroup.org/ogsys/jsp/publications/PublicationDetails.jsp?publicationid=12361
- C114 DRDA V5 Vol. 3: Distributed Data Management Architecture (1176
  pages)
  https://www2.opengroup.org/ogsys/jsp/publications/PublicationDetails.jsp?publicationid=12362

The current version (as of this writing) was published in August 2011.  It supersedes DRDA v4 (C066, C067, C068) published in April 2007, which in turn superseded DRDA V3 (C043, C044, C045) published in January 2004.

Comment: Thanks, but I already have those ones. I found the reference to the manual I'm looking for from Vol. 1 p. 22. Reference manuals are good, in fact, now I'm using them(and a sniffer) to start my development. I'm looking for other manual just because looks like it can guide me better and help to avoid some errors in design.

Comment: Then you need to call IBM.